# how can i make Image object in array to be href

Tags: javascript, arrays, href

Here is an array i declare with images using Javascript. I need those pictures to be href to several sites (different site each picture). Is there any easy solution? I'm new to javascript...

```js
imgSlide = document.getElementById('img');
 

images = new Array();
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = "img1.jpg";
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "img2.jpg";
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "img3.jpg";
images[3] = new Image();
images[3].src = "img4.jpg";
images[4] = new Image();
images[4].src = "img4.jpg";
images[5] = new Image();
images[5].src = "img5.jpg";
images[6] = new Image();
images[6].src = "img6.jpg";
images[7] = new Image();
images[7].src = "img7.jpg";
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two possible solutions:
Adding an anchor around the Imgae or setting an onclick event.

I decided for the onclick event, cause it can be achieved without any further logic behind it (not selecting the a and setting the href).

The other solution is also in an answer here.

If you add an onclick handler dont forget to set the code in an function block.

```js
var imgSlide = document.getElementById('img');
 

var images = new Array();
images[0] = new Image();
images[0].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb_ccw/sample_images/DSCF3300.JPG";
images[0].onclick = function(){window.location ="http://www.w3schools.com";}
images[1] = new Image();
images[1].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb/sample_images/DSCF3165_2.jpg";
images[1].onclick = function(){window.location ="http://forum.xda-developers.com";}
images[2] = new Image();
images[2].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb/sample_images/DSCF3352_2.jpg";
images[2].onclick = function(){window.location ="http://yelp.com";}
images[3] = new Image();
images[3].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb_ccw/sample_images/DSCF1668.JPG";
images[3].onclick = function(){window.location ="http://www.finepix-x100.com";}
images[4] = new Image();
images[4].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb/sample_images/DSCF1773.JPG";
images[4].onclick = function(){window.location ="";}
images[5] = new Image();
images[5].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb/sample_images/DSCF3983_2.jpg";
images[5].onclick = function(){window.location ="";}
images[6] = new Image();
images[6].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb_ccw/sample_images/DSCF2904_2.jpg";
images[6].onclick = function(){window.location ="";}
images[7] = new Image();
images[7].src = "http://www.finepix-x100.com/de/sites/default/files/imagecache/sample_thumb_cw/sample_images/DSCF2564.JPG";
images[7].onclick = function(){window.location ="";}

//length in ms
var duration = 2000;

var i = 0;
    appendImage(i);
for (i; i<images.length; i++){    
    appendImage(i);
}
setInterval(function(){
    imgSlide.removeChild(images[images.length-1]);
    var i = 0;
    appendImage(i);
    for (i; i<images.length; i++){    
        appendImage(i);
    }
},(images.length) * duration);



function appendImage(number){
    setTimeout(function(){
    if (number == 0){
    imgSlide.appendChild(images[number]);
    }else if(number < images.length){
        imgSlide.removeChild(images[number-1]);
        imgSlide.appendChild(images[number]);
    }
    },number * duration);
}
```

```html
<div id = "img"></div>
```

Comment: btw, changed the code, so you have a real slideshow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the images in `a` elements while its `href` points to the image's `src` :

```
var dv = document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = images[i].src;
    a.appendChild(images[i]);
    dv.appendChild(a);
}
```